# Split viewmodel into multiple viewmodels in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

In Knockout.js, when your ViewModel gets quite big, there are different ways to split into multiple ViewModels and it is always a good idea to have a number of smaller ViewModels instead of having one big one. I am using the following approach and not sure if there is any other better way of doing this. Note I am using require.js to define my ViewModels but I am not including that code in the example below for the sake of simplicity. In the following example let's say that I am working on a screen where you can edit courses that a student is enrolled in. Initially I had all courses related functionality (such as add/edit/remove courses) in the StudentViewModel. But I decided to move them to CourseViewModel and then have a reference to the CourseViewModel in StudentViewModel. Please note when creating CourseViewModel, I am passing a reference to student.courses observable array. Is this a good way to have small viewmodels for a View or is there any better way of doing this?

```
function Course(data) {
    data = data || {};
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name); 
}

function Student(data) {
    data = data || {};
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName); 

    this.courses = ko.observableArray($.map(data.courses, function (item) { return new Course(item); }));
}

function CourseViewModel(studentid, courses) {
    var self = this;
    // please note below is a reference to courses observable function 
    self.courses = courses;

    this.addCourse = this.addCourse.bind(this);
    this.editCourse = this.editCourse.bind(this);
    this.removeCourse = this.removeCourse.bind(this);
}

ko.utils.extend(CourseViewModel.prototype, {
    addCourse: function(course) {
        var self = this;
        self.courses.push(course);
    },
    editCourse: function(course) {
        var self = this;
        // find the course and update it 
    },
    removeCourse: function(course) {
        var self = this;
        self.courses.remove(course);
    }
});

// main ViewModel which will be used for binding 
function StudentViewModel(id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.student = ko.observable();
    self.courseViewModel = ko.observable();

    // retrieve student object from server 
    (function() {
        var data = dataService.getStudent(id);
        self.student(new Student(data));
        // please note below I am passing a reference to courses observable function 
        self.courseViewModel(new CourseViewModel(id, student.courses));
    )();
}

// binding 
ko.applyBindings(new StudentViewModel(5));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of doing it is maintain master viewmodel (big fat viewmodel) and define sub viewmodels inside it..

e.g.

```
var MasterVM = {
   subVM1 : SubViewModel1(),
   subVM2: SubViewModel2()
};
```

You can apply bindings with master viewmodel and use sub viewmodel instances whenever and wherever you need.

I tried different techniques but they failed apparently. That's the only reason I moved to DurandalJS from KnockoutJS only. Modular programming works so well without worrying about multiple viewmodels.

Another method of communication between multiple distinct viewmodels is to introduce **Pub-Sub** in your code. There is a very very good plugin for that by Ryan Niemeyer called KO Postbox (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

I found both useful in different scenarios. I would go with first approach though.

Sharing models between multiple viewmodels :

```
//Shared Models for both the ViewModels
var profileModel = function(vm){
    var self = this;
    self.first = ko.observable("Bob");
    self.last = ko.observable("Smith");
    self.vm = ko.observable(vm);
};

var officeModel = function(vm){
    var self = this;
    self.header = ko.observable("Administration");
    self.vm = ko.observable(vm);
};


var viewModel1 =  function(){
    var self = this;
    self.profileModel = new profileModel("Called from viewModel1");
    self.officeModel = new officeModel("office model Called from viewModel1");
};

var viewModel2 =  function(){
    var self = this;
    self.profileModel = new profileModel("Called from viewModel2");
    self.officeModel = new officeModel("office model Called from viewModel2");
};

//the overall view model
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.profile = new profileModel(),
    self.office = new officeModel(),
    self.viewModel1 =  new viewModel1(),
    self.viewModel2 =  new viewModel2()       
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: How would you share model object between sub viewmodels then? In the example I used, there is a Student model which will need to be shared between sub view models. For example I want CourseViewModel to manage Student.Courses and might have AddressViewModel to manage Student.Addresses. In this case I will have the following three sub viewmodels: StudentViewModel, CourseViewModel and AddressViewModel but one Student model. How should I share it between sub viewmodels? Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty simple, just add model like subviewmodels. I will update the code in above answer.

Comment: Cool, I am interested to see how you update my example code with multiple sub viewmodels as per your comment.

Comment: Check as an answer if that helped you. Let's help community to find answer :-)

Comment: @Rahul Thanks,However what you have in your example is not quite what I wanted to do. Essentially you are creating two Models completely separate from each other and there is no link between them. Also in your sub ViewModels you are creating separate Model objects. You are not sharing a Model object between your viewmodels. The way I have my model is Student and it has Courses property as per my example. So per page I have one object of Student model that contains collection  of courses. I wanted to have a separate sub viewmodel to manage course related functioanlity.